# Convert a string from server to HTML in jQuery: equivalent to Html.Raw()?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple chart (using Chartist, but that's irrelevant for my question). I have until now loaded the data for it doing as follows:

```
 <script>
        (function () {
            if ($('#ChartistDebtChart').get(0)) {
                var options = {                    };

                new Chartist.Line('#ChartistDebtChart', {
                     labels: [@Html.Raw(String.Join(", ", Model.Debt.BalanceOverTime.Select(c=> @"'" + c.Item1 + @"'").ToList()))],
                    series: [
                         [@Html.Raw(String.Join(", ", Model.Debt.BalanceOverTime.Select(c=>  ((int)c.Item2)).ToList()))],
                    ]
                }, options);
            }
        })();

        </script>
```

This will render something like:

```
 new Chartist.Line('#ChartistDebtChart', {
                     labels: ['13-02-2018', '16-03-2018', '13-04-2018', '13-04-2018'],
                    series: [
                         [9000, 9056, 9156, 9256],
                    ]
                }, options);
```

Which works perfect!

However, if I do the same where I get the data from my backend. I will use jQuery to perform a GET from our controller. When we write this data, `'13-02-2018', '16-03-2018', '13-04-2018', '13-04-2018'` is not treated as HTML and the data is not shown in the chart.

So my question is: how to get the backend string, when using `GET` in jQuery, to be treated as HTML?

**I have tried the following:**

*Attempt 1: Using Map on a list:*

```
  new Chartist.Line('#DebtDeteriorationGraph', {
                labels: [result.DebtDeteriorationOverTime.map(item => item.Item1).join(", ")],
                series: [
                    ['70000','55000','45000','30000','25000','20000']
                ]
            }, options);
```

Hardcoding the y-values for making it easy, I tried `result.DebtDeteriorationOverTime.map(item => item.Item1).join(", ")` which is treated as ONE string instead of multiple.

*Attempt 2: Serving exact string from server:*

I have made a string exactly like how it should be (`'13-02-2018', '16-03-2018', '13-04-2018', '13-04-2018'`), and inserted it like this:

```
  new Chartist.Line('#DebtDeteriorationGraph', {
                    labels: [result.DebtDeteriorationOverTimeLabelString],
                    series: [
                        ['70000','55000','45000','30000','25000','20000']
                    ]
                }, options);
```

Which is also seen as "1 item" on the x-axis.

*Attempt 3: Get string from server and try parse as HTML*

```
var htmlRes = $('<div/>').html(result.DebtDeteriorationOverTimeLabelString).text();
                    new Chartist.Line('#DebtDeteriorationGraph', {
                        labels: [htmlRes],
                        series: [
                            ['70000','55000','45000','30000','25000','20000']
                        ]
                    }, options);
```

All 3 attempts is treated as a string, and therefore, does NOT have the same effect as when I just run `Html.Raw()` from C#.

Any ideas? :-)

Comment: Note you do not need things like `labels: [@Html.Raw(String.Join(", ", Model.Debt.BalanceOverTime.Select(c=>  ((int)c.Item2)).ToList()))],` - it can simply be `labels: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Debt.BalanceOverTime.Select(c => c.Item2))),`

Comment: From your description I guess you need something like: `labels: result.DebtDeteriorationOverTime.map(item => item.Item1)` (without `[]` and `join`)

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by _how to get the backend string, when using GET in jQuery_ - you do not want a `string` - you want json. How are you getting this data? Are you making an ajax call? And what is the method you are calling?

Comment: @Evk Of course... Damn. How come I didn't see that?! It worked! Thanks a lot !! (can you make a quick answer, then I will award the answer :) )

Comment: @StephenMuecke And thanks for feedback - I will reember to add that next time!

Comment: Your over-complicating it :) Your method should be `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`); where data is a `List<string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying for your response to be treated "as HTML" but you don't really need this. `labels` is javascript array (of strings), so you need javascript array, where each item represents a label. Closest is this attempt:

```
labels: [result.DebtDeteriorationOverTime.map(item => item.Item1).join(", ")]
```

which produces javascript array with one string. Instead you need:

```
labels: result.DebtDeteriorationOverTime.map(item => item.Item1)
```

Because `DebtDeteriorationOverTime` is already array, but not of what you need, so you use `map` to produce array of what you need. No need to join anything or enclose anything in `[]`.

Note that you might also return whole json object that represents chart information (with `labels` and `series` properties) from your api. Then you can just do:

```
new Chartist.Line('#ChartistDebtChart', result.chartData, options);
```